# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - MySqlCommand

Tags: c#, mysql

I am making a application which should work with MySql database. I am getting this error, and I dont know why:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Here is my code:

```
public void rtMean()
    {
        MySqlConnection conect = con.ConnectToMySQL();
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        MySqlDataReader readerMean;

        // OVERENIE, CI UZ STLPEC PRIEMER EXISTUJE

        string query1 = "SELECT * FROM feture";
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query1, conect);
        reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        for (int j=0; j < reader.FieldCount; j++)
        {
            if (reader.GetName(j) == "priemer")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                reader.Close();
                cmd1.Cancel();
                string queryAlterTable = "ALTER TABLE feture ADD COLUMN priemer FLOAT NOT NULL";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryAlterTable, conect); //here I am getting the error
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
```

This should chceck if there is column "priemer" in one of my tables. If yes, it should end / break, and if no, my table should be altered with new column, named "priemer".

Thank you for advices.

EDIT: STACK - TRACE:

```
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
  at WindowsFormsApplication1.ClusteringReady.rtMean() in    c:\Users\Martin\Desktop\CLUSTER\WindowsFormsApplication1\ClusteringReady.cs:line 43
  at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.clusterize_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Martin\Desktop\CLUSTER\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 130
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
  at    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
  at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Martin\Desktop\CLUSTER\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 19
  at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok based on the discussion below, you can run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'feture'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'premier'
```

and if you get `CNT = 0` (in first cell of the result set) then you have to run your ALTER TABLE query ONCE other wise it exists already. Still no need to run a for loop.

Comment: I am getting this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT priemer FROM feture) THEN ALTER TABLE feture ADD COLUMN pr' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, if the first field is not named `priemer` you create a new column trying to close the reader. But you don't stop your loop and thus you execute the second loop, with the reader closed.

There is a better way to find out if your table contains or not the column required

```
bool found = false;
using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection("....................."))
{
    cnn.Open();
    DataTable dt = cnn.GetSchema("COLUMNS", new string[] {null,null,"feture", null});
    foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        if(r["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString() == "priemer")
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found)
    {
        .. create your column here
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I do not stop the loop with break, how do I do it? I would like to check the table col by col and when it finds column named "priemer" it will stop the loop

Comment: The example above avoids to retrive all records from your table when you need only the schema data. A part from the help of GetSchema method you should avoid to change the table where your reader is looping on. Not sure but it seems a dangerous thing to do. Just set a flag and change the table after the loop ends